# Why can I not use Tuple in C#, Visual studio 2010?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, tuples

I have the following installed: 
Visual Studio 2010 Professional,
.NET 4.0.30319

In my program i added the using system and collections generic
but I can not seem to use Tuple ( Using C# )

Can anyone tell me why ?
Thanks

Comment: Is your program targeting .NET 4.0 or 3.5?

Comment: that was the problem :) thanks!

Answer (score 12):

You should choose as target Framework the framework 4 or above, because Tuple is introduced from framework 4 and later.

Answer (score 3):

This code works here like a charm, just started a new C# console project, .Net 4.0:

```
using System;

namespace TestTuple
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var mytuple = new Tuple<string, string, DateTime>("Alexander", "Moor", Convert.ToDateTime("12.03.2009"));
            Console.WriteLine("{1},{0} born {2}", mytuple.Item1, mytuple.Item2, mytuple.Item3);
        }
    }
}
```